# Why using the default React Google Maps getting "TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function"?

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, components

Using almost the default npm template for google maps I get the error, that cannot call a class as a function. Where ever I read, all of them were missing the `extends Component` part though I do have it

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Map, GoogleApiWrapper } from "google-maps-react";

const mapStyles = {
  width: "100%",
  height: "100%",
};

export class MapContainer extends Component {
  state = {
    showingInfoWindow: false, // Hides or shows the InfoWindow
    activeMarker: {}, // Shows the active marker upon click
    selectedPlace: {}, // Shows the InfoWindow to the selected place upon a marker
  };
  onMarkerClick = (props, marker, e) =>
    this.setState({
      selectedPlace: props,
      activeMarker: marker,
      showingInfoWindow: true,
    });

  onClose = (props) => {
    if (this.state.showingInfoWindow) {
      this.setState({
        showingInfoWindow: false,
        activeMarker: null,
      });
    }
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <Map
        google={this.props.google}
        zoom={14}
        style={mapStyles}
        initialCenter={{
          lat: -1.2884,
          lng: 36.8233,
        }}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default GoogleApiWrapper({
  apiKey: "API KEY",
})(MapContainer);
```

And once I import and use it I get:

```
import { MapContainer } from "./submitMap";
```

Error in browser:

```
Warning: The <Map /> component appears to have a render method, but doesn't extend React.Component. This is likely to cause errors. Change Map to extend React.Component instead.
    at Map (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:2080:7)
    at MapContainer (http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:13540:5)
```

I can't find an issue with this. Can anybody advise?

Comment: Hey @YoungDad, do you have the full stacktrace you could share?

Comment: I added the browser, where it complains about the React.Component, though I have this one. The Map from the node module has `export class Map extends React.Component<IMapProps, any> {}`

Answer (score -1):

Your browser error seems to want your Map component to have the `extend React.Component` and it seems like you are returning Map directly in your render. If you want to do that, you'll have to go into the Map component and edit it to extend React.Component